# Update existing package on CRAN

Tags: r, r-package, cran

I have an R package already on CRAN and recently I have made some adjustment to the package and wanted to update the version on CRAN, do I just submit the latest version like as if it's the first version? Or is it another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to re-submit the package. See the [CRAN policies document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html#Re_002dsubmission)

Comment: Thank you so much for responding me! This is very useful!